# Mapnik can't determine image type

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapnik

I'm trying to load an image from a WMS into mapnik, but I'm getting an error `Unhandled rejection Error: image_reader: can't determine type from input data`. The code, stripped down, is

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const mapnik = require('mapnik');

request(`${wmsUrl}/GetMap`, {
  qs: {
    bbox: '-90,32,-89,33',
    format: 'image/png',
    height: 200,
    layers: '5',
    request: 'GetMap',
    'srs(crs)': 'EPSG:4326,
    styles: 'default',
    version: '1.1',
    width: 200,
  },
}).then(res => {
  const buffer = new Buffer(res);
  return mapnik.Image.fromBytesSync(buffer); // This is the error line
});
```

I've run the request manually and it works, and I've inspected the buffer and it looks good (i.e. has 'PNG' at the start). I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else encounters something similar to this, the problem is that `request` (or in this case `request-promise`) assumes that the response body should be a string and implicitly performs `toString` on it. To solve, the request should be

```
request(url, {
  qs: { ... },
  encoding: null,
}).then({ ... });
```

See more details here: https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by specifying BOTH the `responseType` and the `Content-Type` header:

```
return axios.get(url, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'image/png',
    },
});
```